Applications packaged with nuitka cannot run
I am using Nuitka to package my PyQt5 application and running it in source code without any exceptions. But running after packaging will report an error:
 Tips: QFluentWidgets Pro is now released. Click https://qfluentwidgets.com/pages/pro to learn more about it.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\18079\DOCUME~1\DOWNLO~1\MUSICD~1.DIS\MusicDownloader.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\18079\DOCUME~1\DOWNLO~1\MUSICD~1.DIS\window\main.py", line 6, in <module window.main>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\18079\DOCUME~1\DOWNLO~1\MUSICD~1.DIS\Interface\settings.py", line 11, in <module Interface.settings>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\18079\DOCUME~1\DOWNLO~1\MUSICD~1.DIS\helper\localmusicsHelper.py", line 9, in <module helper.localmusicsHelper>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\18079\DOCUME~1\DOWNLO~1\MUSICD~1.DIS\fleep\__init__.py", line 15, in <module fleep>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\18079\\DOCUME~1\\DOWNLO~1\\MUSICD~1.DIS\\fleep\\data.json'

Before reinstalling the system, I was able to package and run it normally, but now it cannot run under any circumstances, even with administrator privileges.
This is my packaging command:
nuitka --standalone --plugin-enable=pyqt5 --windows-icon-from-ico=icon.ico MusicDownloader.py

This is the output of my execution of nuitka -- version:
C:\Users\18079>nuitka --version
2.3.4
Commercial: None
Python: 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
Flavor: CPython Official
Executable: C:\Users\18079\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
OS: Windows
Arch: x86_64
WindowsRelease: 11
Nuitka-Scons: Non downloaded winlibs-gcc 'C:\Users\18079\Documents\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe' is being ignored, Nuitka is very
Nuitka-Scons: dependent on the precise one.
Version C compiler: ~\AppData\Local\Nuitka\Nuitka\Cache\DOWNLO~1\gcc\x86_64\13.2.0-16.0.6-11.0.1-msvcrt-r1\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe (gcc 13.2.0).

I tried running on different computers, but none of them worked.

The error is clear, the package expects a file that doesn't exist. Check that "fleep" and eventually reinstall it, but ensure that you're using the same Python interpreter and the same venv as the rest of the package.
